# Query de dataset que mostra ultimo ID criado dando erro

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, dataset

Estou fazendo um formulário de cadastro de pessoas o qual quando termino a inserção dos dados ele mostra uma `MessageBox` dizendo com qual ID a pessoa foi cadastrada.
Para isso uso uma `query` do meu `dataset`(estou usando Entity Framework model first), mas por algum motivo esta dando erro de que "Uma ou mais linhas contêm valores que violam as restrições non-null, unique ou foreign-key.", devido isso creio que seja erro no código do banco, talvez não.

Segue o codigo da query:

```
SELECT MAX(ID_Pacientes) as UltimoID FROM Pacientes_TCC
```

O campo `ID_Pacientes` é de autro incremento e é chave primaria.

Codigo onde implemento a query:

```
 private void btnInserir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Pacientes_TCCTableAdapter TaPaciente = new Pacientes_TCCTableAdapter();

            TaPaciente.Insert(txtNome.Text, txtCPF.Text, txtRG.Text, cbxSexo.Text, dtpData.Value, txtCidade.Text, txtEstado.Text, txtBairro.Text, txtCEP.Text,
                txtRua.Text, txtNumero.Text, txtCelular.Text, txtFixo.Text, txtEmail.Text, cbxConvenio.Text);

            if (MessageBox.Show("Pessoa gravado com o ID" +TaPaciente.UltimoID()+ " Deseja fazer outro cadastro?", "Confirma", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
            {
                Close();
            }



        }
```

Comment: Não entendi bem, um campo `identity` (auto incremento) só pode ser chave primária, não estrangeira...

Comment: Desculpe, foi erro de digitação, o campo ID_Pacientes é primary key.

Comment: Entendi. Edite sua pergunta pra não deixar dúvidas.

Comment: Mas a mensagem não tem relação com o `select max`, parece ser no insert. Algum campo not null está sem valor ou o valor de alguma FK está inválido. Já tentou debugar e ver os valores que estão sendo passados pro `entity` ao fazer o insert?

Comment: o `insert` funciona normalmente, apesar de eu ter tido problema com ele antes, mas depois da inserção eu verifico os campos e esta tudo ok, o campo ID_Pacientes e a Fk mas ela não passa pelo `insert` por ser auto incremento.

Comment: Assim como o @RicardoPontual mencionou, o erro está no seu `insert`. Um teste simples é você substituir os parâmetros atuais do seu `insert`por valores fixos.